# How to style the Android status bar on Nativescript?

Tags: javascript, android, css, xml, nativescript

The problem I'm having (and for which I haven't been able to find a solution) is how to style the status bar in `NativeScript`. I tried to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-statusbar)

but when I put the

```
<x:StatusBar android:barStyle="#0E0A0E"/>
```

line wherever in the `main-page.xml` file (I guess the correct place is below the `<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:x="nativescript-statusbar">` line, but tried to find out if that was the problem) the status bar turns black and the entire app change to a blank page... Obviously not what I'm looking for. At this moment all I have is a new `NativeScript` project (no template).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried the plugin you linked to, so can't comment on that, but I'm using this file: https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/cddf211204dfd21efde2559bb84674f94fcd6d9a/app/shared/status-bar-util.ts

You reference it in `main`, which is also shown in that repo.

Comment: And to piggy back here is a post detailing things a little bit https://bradmartin.net/2016/03/10/fullscreen-and-navigation-bar-color-in-a-nativescript-android-app/